# Javascript Function Valid Username

Tags: javascript

What's the best way/right way to create a javascript function that checks to see that the user has adhered to the valid character list below (user would enter a username through a html form) - if character list is adhered to function would return true - otherwise false.

```
validcharacters = '1234567890-_.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
```

Comment: Don't use loops and nested loops because it's not efficient. You have to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 15):

```
function usernameIsValid(username) {
    return /^[0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+$/.test(username);
}
```

This function returns true if the regex matches. The regex matches if the `username` is composed only of number, letter and `_`, `.`, `-` characters.

You could also do it without regex:

```
function usernameIsValid(username) {
    var validcharacters = '1234567890-_.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    for (var i = 0, l = username.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if (validcharacters.indexOf(username.substr(i, 1)) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

For this one, we iterate over all characters in `username` and verify that the character is in `validcharacters`.

Comment: could you explain use of `!!`, isn't it same with `username.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+$/)`?

Comment: The converts `.match`'s return value to a boolean. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript

Comment: Or do `/^[0-9a-zA-Z_.\-]+$/.test(username)`. This may be a cheaper operation than match.

Comment: Can not remove the first char when backspace to revise?

Answer (score 0):

one way is to read each character from the input field and use the indexOf() function